# How to perform some third party calculation on each row of the data frame in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a R data frame which i have converted into RDD by calling createDataFrame function. RDD has multiple columns which should be used to calculate a new column. 
I need to call  AmericanOption function of RQuantLib R package through SparkR and update the returned value into new column of the same data frame. Normally we can do this with foreach in other programming languages but have no idea how we can do this in SparkR as map function is also missing as documented https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to

1. transform RDD into RDDLoL, a list of lists,
2. SparkR:::parallelize RDDLoL into parallelRDD
3. call
   res <- collect(SparkR:::lapply(parallelRDD , foo))
4. attached res to a new column of the original data frame.